# Update component in generic way

Tags: reactjs, antd

Here's my [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-create-react-app-t4hvm)

Now I change the title when user select an item on selectList(**antd component**) using `e.target.textContent`.

is there any way that i can show all the values, now I'm only able to show one select list value.

I want something like this : `value from first dropdown / value from second dropdown`

```
<DropDown>
  <DropDown.DropDownTitle>
    This title will update after user selection // this should be updated when user select 
  </DropDown.DropDownTitle>
  <DropDown.DropDownBody>
    <Select
      defaultValue="lucy"
      style={{ width: 120 }}
      onChange={handleChange}
    >
      <Option value="jack">another</Option>
      <Option value="lucy">another 2</Option>
    </Select>
    <Select
      defaultValue="lucy"
      style={{ width: 120 }}
      onChange={handleChange}
    >
      <Option value="jack">another 3</Option>
      <Option value="lucy">another 4</Option>
    </Select>
  </DropDown.DropDownBody>
</DropDown>
```

Comment: Where are you storing the title value?

Comment: @JMadelaine in context 
DropDownContext.js

Answer (score 1):

I can see you're using `antd`, I believe it's better to use `Select` with `multiple selection`, it will set the values the way you want it. 
here's their sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/cpive

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did use antd in index.js

Comment: if this is the right answer for you kindly mark it as correct and give upvote :)

Comment: no that's not the right answer and also it's not relevant to my question